# NullPointerException on dialog.dismiss()

Tags: php, android

I'm following [this](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) tutorial on how to upload image to server, but I get NullPointerException on last `dialog.dismiss();` that is before `return serverResponseCode;`

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
            });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                             + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         } 
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Also, does anyone know how to also send some string value from the app, and how to receive it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to propose you an [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) clear solution, instead of complicating it with threads. In other words use Thread for background-only operations and use ASyncTask where you work with UI thread also.

Here is short example for you:

```
//[...]
// here is your handler for button:
uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Uploader().execute(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
    });
//[...]



private class Uploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");

        // do here all UI operations -> show Dialog window, change texts etc.
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        // do here background operation, e.g. connect to web
        // return true for success, false for error

        String fileToUpload = params[0]; // get file name that was sent from OnClick listener

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // hide Dialogs here and update texts
        dialog.dismiss();

        if (result) {
            // if success, show something
        }
        else {
            // if error, show something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dismissing your dialog in your background thread. You should do that inside your **runOnUiThread**.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable in your activity such as

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
```

and init it in onCreate

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadServer.this);
dialog.setMessage("Uploading..");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setTitle("");
```

Later you can use it wherever you want. But before show your dialog you should check

```
if(dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing())
dialog.show();
```

And when you want to dismis

```
if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
dialog.dismiss();
```

With null checks you can avoid null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Well, it's not professional. Good developer should know what his code is doing and should now when his variables will be null and when not. If you write your code well, I'm pretty sure you don't have to check if it's null, unless some function returns object that might be null for some reasons.

Comment: @krzynek91 oh sorry i forget you are developing applications with 3 activities which contains 50 lines code. You are right.

Comment: Well, from time to time we are used also to write small applications :) Above example is exactly this what you mean. If we forget now about such little things, we will write huge application full of similar issues. Don't be offended, I'm just trying force people to write as good apps as possible.

Answer (score -1):

check if dialog!=null then dismiss.as you have written dialog.dismiss() in each condition i think you are trying to dismiss dialog which is already dismissed